# How can I connect mains to a 230V heating band?

Tags: power, transformer, mains, heat

I am planning on using some 230V heating bands for a project of mine. I was wondering what kind of equipment I would need to connect this heating band, which has +,- pins to mains. What kind of equipment would I need to convert the L,N and G cables of a mains power supply to be able to connect to the heating bands?

EDIT#1
The link to my heating band is:https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heating-elements/9209956/.It is a 235W heating band. Would I need a 230VAC to 230VDC inverter for this project? If so, what is the cheapest way I could source one?
I do not have much experience working with mains.

Comment: You need to provide more information before we can give an answer.  This is important because connecting any device to the mains involves a risk of equipment damage and bodily harm. What are the specifications of these bands? Especially the required input power in both voltage and watts.  If they have pins labeled +/- it is likely that a DC voltage is required. That means some sort of AC/DC converter will be needed. How much experience so you have working with mains connected equipment?

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: It seems the link you've provided is region specific, I am unable to open it.

Answer (score 0):

The data is insufficient. Apparently the link you have added is region specific. Most heating pads work in AC. Using that basis, the + and - you have mentioned are Live and Neutral. However if you intend to earth your connections, just short the neutral wire and the ground wire. Your heater works on general wall sockets.

Since the power specified is 235 watts, The Voltage will be 230VAC and Current 1A which works fine in a normal socket